# Superfish dropdown goes behind when published to server on IE

Tags: superfish

Its fine when I run it on Visual Studio but then it goes behind if deployed to web server on IE. It works perfectly with Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the technique with IE was to supersede via its z-index and making the div at position:relative. See code example below.

Given this HTML.

```
<div id="header">
    <ul class="sf-menu"></ul>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

And, the CSS..

```
#header{z-index:2;position:relative;
}
#content{z-index:1;position:relative;
}
```

Then the superfish dropdown in IE should now always be on top of content.